# Looping Help PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am new in Programming. I have a question can anybody help me that how can I do this. below is my Question. Please take a look and let me know the process that how can I do this.

> Have you ever had to send out marriage announcements? If not, this is
>   how it goes. You take the invitation, place it in the envelope, lick
>   the envelope, seal the envelope, then send it off. Then you take the
>   next invitation off the stack of 99 remaining invitations, place it in
>   an envelope, lick the envelope, seal... You get the idea! It is a
>   boring and repetitive task! Wouldn't it be great if there was an
>   easier way? Well, in programming and in JavaScript there is! The
>   process is called "looping." With the right planning, looping will
>   turn your cute little scripts into massive workhorses. A loop
>   statement checks to see if some condition is true, and if that
>   condition is true, it executes a chunk of code. After the code is
>   executed, the condition is checked again. If it is true, the process
>   starts over again; if it is false, the loop stops and the rest of the
>   code continues along. If we think about our wedding invitation example
>   as a loop, we would first check if there are any invitations left. If
>   there are, we would stuff, lick, and seal the next envelope. If there
>   are no envelopes left, we would stop.

Please help me I am waiting for the answer.

Thanks.
shariar

Comment: that is very clear. What are you unable to understand?

Comment: Hi raheel,
I understand that what the question is.. but my question is that how can I do this...? as I am new so, if you can please help me.

Thanks.
shariar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Total invites = 100 
counter = 0

 (for counter = 1 ; counter <= total invites ; counter ++)  
   {
     place it in the envelope // might have more conditions ex: if envelope is broken , discard current , take next empty envelope
     lick the envelope // might have more conditions ex: Toung missing!! :P
    seal the envelope // might have more conditions
    send it off // might have more conditions
}
```

Something like this?

Comment: Yes Bender,
I think like this as you showed but... how can i manage this?
can you explain me about details.

Comment: I asked the minimal of the conditions. It will be better for more statement checking. I want to know how to check these statement?

Comment: @ShariarHossain minimal conditions might going to cause some issues.. I suggest you to go with most of the conditions that you can imagine that might interrupt the execution.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be from [this tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptstatements.php). At the bottom of that very page, it says:

> Do not despair if you have not grasped all the details discussed above, as we will be covering them further in a later lesson.

In fact, three clicks on [Continue] button later, there is a whole page on `while` loops; then the next page after that, `for` is covered.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @neelsg Please read the answer, not just see that there's a link and "Recommend deletion".

Comment: @Emil I don't see how it answers the question except that it basically says: Go back to this linked tutorial and click [Continue] until you understand. This answer becomes useless if the link becomes invalid

Comment: There is a link. Then there is a quote saying to read something on *another website*. Then there is description of where to read something on *another website*. This is a link-only answer.

Comment: @neelsg and Quentin: You're right, I should probably have read the answer properly myself.